# How to create two XSSFWorkbook objects with the same bytes

Tags: java, excel, xssf

I am trying to write a test to check that an Excel file I have created in code is exactly the same as a resource file (same formatting, same cell contents, etc).

One idea was to convert to byte arrays and check that the byte arrays are equal. Unfortunately, I am having trouble with this approach as the excel format seems to include a timestamp of when the file was created.

For example, this code prints `false`.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Workbook workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    workbook1.write(baos1);
    byte[] bytes1 = baos1.toByteArray();

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    Workbook workbook2 = new XSSFWorkbook();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    workbook2.write(baos2);
    byte[] bytes2 = baos2.toByteArray();

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes1));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes2));
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(bytes1, bytes2));
  }
}
```

Does anyone know a way around this problem? Is it possible to create `XSSFWorkbook` instances that are guaranteed to be the same? Alternatively, is there another way around this problem?

Comment: I can't understand why you're wondering, however topic seems to be interesting.

Comment: @xenteros I'm trying to write a unit test to check that an excel file I've created in code is exactly the same as one I've created earlier and saved as a resource. Unfortunately, this doesn't work because the resulting files are not the same.

Comment: Of course they aren't - they differ in headers because of a timestamp

Comment: @cppbeginner did you solve the issue?

Comment: Not really. It was a while ago now but I ended up using a completely different approach